# Modify subset sum

Tags: arrays, algorithm

**Given a array of N positive integers. Let the minimum element be L and sum of all elements is S.**

I need to find out if, for each integer X,(where X is between L and S inclusive) can a subset of the array be chosen such that the sum of elements in this subset is equal to X.

*EXAMPLE* :

Let `N=5` and array is `{4,8,2,1,16}` . Then here all elements can be made between 1 to 31 so here ans is "yes".

If suppose `N=4` and array is `{5,1,2,7}` . Then for values between 1 and 15 the values 4 and 11 cannot be made. **So answer here is "no".**

Comment: You need to provide what you have tried.

Comment: @harold No. {1,2,3} is a counter example.

Comment: @herohuyongtao I know to find the minimum number that cant be returned by this array,But dont know to how to solve this problem

Comment: @user2357112 I just did, so I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know to find the minimum number that cant be returned by this array,But dont know to how to solve this problem

First, does the array have only one element? If so, the answer is yes.

Otherwise, find the minimum impossible sum. Is it greater than S? If so, the answer is yes. Otherwise, the answer is no. (If the minimum is less than L, the array doesn't contain 1, and S-1 is an impossible sum.)

To find the lowest impossible sum, we sort the input, then find the lowest impossible sum of each prefix of the array. In Python:

```
def lowest_impossible_sum(nums):
    nums = sorted(nums)
    partial_sum = 0
    for num in nums:
        if num > partial_sum + 1:
            return partial_sum + 1
        partial_sum += num
    return partial_sum + 1
```

Proof of correctness by induction:

Let A be the sorted array. If `A[0] > 1`, then 1 is the lowest impossible sum. Otherwise, the elements of `A[:1]` can produce all sums up to `sum(A[:1])`.

Suppose for induction that subsets of `A[:k]` can be selected to produce all sums up to `sum(A[:k])`.

- If `A[k] > sum(A[:k]) + 1`, then `sum(A[:k]) + 1` is the lowest impossible sum; it can't be produced by a subset of `A[:k]`, and adding elements that aren't in `A[:k]` won't help, as they're all too big.
- If `A[k] <= sum(A[:k]) + 1`, then subsets of `A[:k+1]` can produce every sum up to `sum(A[:k+1])`. Every sum up to `sum(A[:k])` can already be produced by the inductive hypothesis, and sums from `sum(A[:k]) + 1` to `sum(A[:k+1])` can be produced by selecting `A[k]` and a suitable subset of `A[:k]` adding up to what's left.

Let x be the first index such that `A[x] > sum(A[:x]) + 1`, or `len(A)` if there is no such index. By induction, every sum up to `sum(A[:x])` is possible. However, whether because x is past the end of the array or because `A[x] > sum(A[:x]) + 1`, it is impossible to produce the sum `sum(A[:x]) + 1`. Thus, we need merely search for x and return `sum(A[:x]) + 1`. That is what the algorithm does.

Comment: could you please provide an efficient algorithm as according to my algorithm i will be checking for each number starting from one,which is too inefficient for large N

Comment: @user3219308: That's a pretty inefficient algorithm for finding the lowest impossible sum, then. I'll edit in an algorithm that ought to solve both problems quickly.

Comment: There's a still an issue where minimal number could be smaller than L.  However, I am 99.9% convinced that if 1 is not in the array and the array contains more than 1 element - you cannot get all sums. (this claim requires a proof!). However, this solution fails for arr = [5], for example, as minimal element that cannot be achieved is 1, and the answer is still 'yes'.

Comment: @amit: Crap, it starts at L. Deleting and (probably) fixing...

Comment: @amit: Okay, fixed. If 1 isn't in the array, S-1 is an impossible sum, so it's an easy modification.

Comment: Nice, I had an alternative proof: Let `A` be an array where `|A|>1`. Assume 1 is not in A. Let `x=max{A}`. Note that `L<=x<x+1<x+x'<=S` where `x'` is some other element in `A` (there is one because `|A| > 1`). However, `x+1` cannot be achieved. QED.

Comment: Also, please prove correctness of your algorithm to find lowest impossible sum, as I am not sure why it works.

Comment: Working on that. I know why it works, but getting it into clear terminology is a bit frustrating.

Comment: @user2357112 i am too unable to get correctness of this algorithm

Comment: @amit: Correctness proven, unless I've made an error.

Comment: @user2357112 heads off..excellent..:)

Comment: @user2357112 Proof seems correct, got the idea - thanks. nice solution. +1.

Answer (score 0):

First sort all elements in the array. If you want to get all the values between L and S from the elements of the array, then **L = 1** and the elements should be in the form of 2^i . And the greatest element may not be of form 2^i because the sum need not be of the form (2^i - 1).

Comment: See amit's counterexample.

Comment: @user2357112 : Thanks for pointing out. Now I have corrected the algo. The greatest element may not be of form 2^i.

Comment: Still wrong. `{1, 1, 1}` is a counterexample to what I think you're trying to say.