# Finding the smallest integer who's not a sum of a sorted array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, performance, memory-efficient

I just got back from an exam which had a question that I just don't know how to even approach:

> Given a sorted array (each element in the array is greater than or
>   equal to the previous one) **arr** of positive integer, find the
>   smallest *positive* integer that is not a sum of the elements of the
>   array **arr**, where each element in the array *can only appear once*
>   in the sum.

So for example, given the array {1, 2, 4, 6},

- 1 is not the answer, since it is the sum 1.
- 2 is not, for the same reason.
- 3 is not, since 3 = 1 + 2
- ...
- 13 is not, since 13 = 1 + 2 + 4 + 6
- 14 is the answer, since it is not a sum of elements in the array (where each element appears once).

Therefore the result would be 14.

The algorithm was required to be as efficient as possible. I have written two very inefficient algorithms, one iterating over every number from 1 onwards, and checking with recursion whether it is the sum; and another algorithm documenting all possible sums of the array in a very large array, and checking each time if there are two consecutive sums whose difference is greater than one (therefore returning the least integer that lies between those sums).

p.s. - we where required to write it in Java, but if you have a solution in another language like C or Python, please use whatever language you're comfortable with.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Comment: First try to do your assignment yourself  if you face any problem then ask specific problem.

Comment: I think this is a perfectly acceptable question.

Comment: "I think this is a perfectly acceptable question" It's fine to ask the question, provided OP also asks a specific question about a problem they faced whilst trying to solve it; that also somewhat implies they show their attempted solution.

Comment: @AndyTurner how does one show their attempted solution towards a question of an algorithmic nature?

Comment: @Rishav "we where required to write it in Java" By showing the Java written.

Comment: @Rishav May I suggest you re-take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to remind yourself what this site is about, what kinds of questions fit here, and which do not.

Comment: I think this might require a dynamic programming solution because I think I see the optimal subproblem property (or whatever its called lol; just giving some insight if any)

Comment: you might have better luck asking this question the [computer science stack exchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com/). i certainly want to know the answer to this question too

Comment: This is actually [pretty simple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21348887/modify-subset-sum). (The linked question isn't quite the same, but part of the answer is an answer to this question.)

Comment: @user2357112 nice find